# Module not found: Error: Can't resolve 'fs' after using Rollup

Tags: typescript, npm, create-react-app, rollupjs

First off, I'm aware this has been asked a zillion times across the web, so I apologize in advance for posting what seems like a duplicate. I've tried everything I could find, although nothing seems to help.

Issue:
I'm having an issue when importing a package created using Rollup.js for React using Typescript. Below is the full error when importing and using any component from my package:

```
Compiled with problems:
×
ERROR in ./node_modules/clone-stats/index.js 1:11-30
Module not found: Error: Can't resolve 'fs' in 'C:\Users\User\Documents\test\node_modules\clone-stats'

ERROR in ./node_modules/css/lib/stringify/source-map-support.js 9:9-22
Module not found: Error: Can't resolve 'fs' in 'C:\Users\User\Documents\test\node_modules\css\lib\stringify'

ERROR in ./node_modules/glob-stream/node_modules/glob/glob.js 42:9-22
Module not found: Error: Can't resolve 'fs' in 'C:\Users\User\Documents\test\node_modules\glob-stream\node_modules\glob'

ERROR in ./node_modules/glob-stream/node_modules/glob/sync.js 3:9-22
Module not found: Error: Can't resolve 'fs' in 'C:\Users\User\Documents\test\node_modules\glob-stream\node_modules\glob'

ERROR in ./node_modules/graceful-fs/graceful-fs.js 1:9-22
Module not found: Error: Can't resolve 'fs' in 'C:\Users\User\Documents\test\node_modules\graceful-fs'

ERROR in ./node_modules/import-fresh/node_modules/resolve-from/index.js 5:11-24
Module not found: Error: Can't resolve 'fs' in 'C:\Users\User\Documents\test\node_modules\import-fresh\node_modules\resolve-from'

ERROR in ./node_modules/mkdirp/index.js 2:9-22
Module not found: Error: Can't resolve 'fs' in 'C:\Users\User\Documents\test\node_modules\mkdirp'

ERROR in ./node_modules/path-type/index.js 6:11-24
Module not found: Error: Can't resolve 'fs' in 'C:\Users\User\Documents\test\node_modules\path-type'
ERROR in ./node_modules/resolve/lib/async.js 1:9-22
Module not found: Error: Can't resolve 'fs' in 'C:\Users\User\Documents\test\node_modules\resolve\lib'

ERROR in ./node_modules/resolve/lib/sync.js 2:9-22
Module not found: Error: Can't resolve 'fs' in 'C:\Users\User\Documents\test\node_modules\resolve\lib'

ERROR in ./node_modules/twin.macro/macro.js 9:9-22
Module not found: Error: Can't resolve 'fs' in 'C:\Users\User\Documents\test\node_modules\twin.macro'

ERROR in ./node_modules/twin.macro/node_modules/babel-plugin-macros/node_modules/cosmiconfig/dist/readFile.js 8:33-46
Module not found: Error: Can't resolve 'fs' in 'C:\Users\User\Documents\test\node_modules\twin.macro\node_modules\babel-plugin-macros\node_modules\cosmiconfig\dist'
```

Below is my package.json:

```
{
    "name": "test",
    "version": "0.1.0",
    "main": "dist/cjs/index.js",
    "module": "dist/esm/index.js",
    "files": [
        "dist"
    ],
    "types": "dist/index.d.ts",
    "peerDependencies": {
        "react": "^18.2.0",
        "react-dom": "^18.2.0"
    },
    "scripts": {
        "pack": "npm run remove-dist & copyfiles -u 1 src/components/**/* dist",
        "rollup": "npm run remove-dist & rollup -c",
        "start": "react-app-rewired start",
        "remove-dist": "rd /s /q \"dist\"",
        "test": "react-app-rewired test",
        "eject": "react-app-rewired eject",
        "storybook": "start-storybook -p 6006 -s public",
        "build:tailwind": "postcss src/scss/base.scss -o src/scss/tailwind.scss",
        "build-storybook": "build-storybook -s public",
        "tscheck": "tsc"
    },
    "dependencies": {
        "@babel/polyfill": "^7.12.1",
        "@coreui/coreui": "^4.2.2",
        "@fortawesome/fontawesome-svg-core": "^6.1.2",
        "@fortawesome/free-brands-svg-icons": "^6.1.2",
        "@fortawesome/free-regular-svg-icons": "^6.1.2",
        "@fortawesome/free-solid-svg-icons": "^6.1.2",
        "@fortawesome/react-fontawesome": "^0.2.0",
        "@material-ui/core": "^4.12.4",
        "@monaco-editor/react": "^4.4.6",
        "@rollup/plugin-babel": "^6.0.3",
        "@rollup/plugin-commonjs": "^23.0.4",
        "@rollup/plugin-json": "^6.0.0",
        "@testing-library/jest-dom": "^5.16.4",
        "@testing-library/react": "^13.3.0",
        "@testing-library/user-event": "^13.5.0",
        "@types/jest": "^27.5.2",
        "@types/node": "^16.11.47",
        "@types/react-dom": "^18.0.6",
        "@types/react-grid-layout": "^1.3.2",
        "babel-cli": "^6.26.0",
        "babel-plugin-macros": "^3.1.0",
        "body-scroll-lock": "^4.0.0-beta.0",
        "constants": "^0.0.2",
        "cookie-universal": "^2.2.2",
        "crypto-js": "^4.1.1",
        "env-cmd": "^10.1.0",
        "gsap": "^3.10.4",
        "module": "^1.2.5",
        "os": "^0.1.2",
        "path": "^0.12.7",
        "postcss-cli": "^10.0.0",
        "react-admin": "^4.2.7",
        "react-animations": "^1.0.0",
        "react-app-rewired": "^2.2.1",
        "react-brackets": "^0.4.6",
        "react-burger-menu": "^3.0.8",
        "react-grid-layout": "^1.3.4",
        "react-scripts": "5.0.1",
        "react-spinners": "^0.13.8",
        "react-vertical-timeline-component": "^3.6.0",
        "reactive-button": "^1.3.12",
        "rollup-plugin-copy": "^3.4.0",
        "rollup-plugin-css-only": "^4.3.0",
        "rollup-plugin-import-css": "^3.2.1",
        "rollup-plugin-node-polyfills": "^0.2.1",
        "rollup-plugin-peer-deps-external": "^2.2.4",
        "rollup-plugin-postcss": "^4.0.2",
        "rollup-plugin-ts": "^3.2.0",
        "rollup-plugin-uglify": "^6.0.4",
        "socket.io-client": "^4.5.2",
        "stream": "^0.0.2",
        "styled-components": "^5.3.8",
        "twin.macro": "^2.8.2",
        "universal-cookie": "^4.0.4",
        "web-vitals": "^2.1.4"
    },
    "eslintConfig": {
        "extends": [
            "react-app",
            "react-app/jest"
        ],
        "overrides": [
            {
                "files": [
                    "**/*.stories.*"
                ],
                "rules": {
                    "import/no-anonymous-default-export": "off"
                }
            }
        ]
    },
    "browserslist": {
        "production": [
            ">0.2%",
            "not dead",
            "not op_mini all"
        ],
        "development": [
            "last 1 chrome version",
            "last 1 firefox version",
            "last 1 safari version"
        ]
    },
    "devDependencies": {
        "@babel/cli": "^7.21.0",
        "@babel/core": "^7.21.0",
        "@babel/preset-env": "^7.20.2",
        "@babel/preset-react": "^7.18.6",
        "@babel/preset-typescript": "^7.18.6",
        "@rollup/plugin-node-resolve": "^15.0.1",
        "@rollup/plugin-typescript": "^11.0.0",
        "@storybook/addon-actions": "^6.5.10",
        "@storybook/addon-essentials": "^6.5.10",
        "@storybook/addon-interactions": "^6.5.10",
        "@storybook/addon-links": "^6.5.10",
        "@storybook/addon-postcss": "^2.0.0",
        "@storybook/builder-webpack5": "^6.5.10",
        "@storybook/manager-webpack5": "^6.5.10",
        "@storybook/node-logger": "^6.5.10",
        "@storybook/preset-create-react-app": "^4.1.2",
        "@storybook/react": "^6.5.10",
        "@storybook/testing-library": "^0.0.13",
        "@types/react": "^18.0.28",
        "@types/react-burger-menu": "^2.8.3",
        "@types/react-vertical-timeline-component": "^3.3.3",
        "autoprefixer": "^10.4.8",
        "babel-loader": "^9.1.2",
        "babel-plugin-named-exports-order": "^0.0.2",
        "copyfiles": "^2.4.1",
        "dotenv-webpack": "^8.0.1",
        "mini-css-extract-plugin": "^2.7.2",
        "postcss": "^8.4.14",
        "process": "^0.11.10",
        "prop-types": "^15.8.1",
        "react": "^18.2.0",
        "react-dom": "^18.2.0",
        "rimraf": "^4.2.0",
        "rollup": "^3.18.0",
        "rollup-plugin-dts": "^5.2.0",
        "rollup-plugin-node-builtins": "^2.1.2",
        "rollup-plugin-node-globals": "^1.4.0",
        "rollup-plugin-typescript2": "^0.34.1",
        "tailwindcss": "^3.1.8",
        "ts-loader": "^9.4.2",
        "tslib": "^2.5.0",
        "typescript": "^4.9.5",
        "webpack": "^5.74.0",
        "webpack-cli": "^5.0.1",
        "webpack-node-externals": "^3.0.0"
    },
    "browser": {
        "fs": false,
        "os": false,
        "path": false
    }
}
```

Below is my rollup.config.js:

```
const resolve = require("@rollup/plugin-node-resolve");
const commonjs = require("@rollup/plugin-commonjs");
const typescript = require("@rollup/plugin-typescript");
const dts = require("rollup-plugin-dts");
const json = require("@rollup/plugin-json");
const nodePolyfills = require("rollup-plugin-node-polyfills");
const peerDepsExternal = require("rollup-plugin-peer-deps-external");
const postcss = require("rollup-plugin-postcss");
const builtins = require("rollup-plugin-node-builtins");
const globals = require("rollup-plugin-node-globals");
const babel = require("@rollup/plugin-babel").babel;
const uglify = require("rollup-plugin-uglify").uglify;
const copy = require("rollup-plugin-copy");
const packageJson = require("./package.json");

module.exports = [
    {
        input: "src/components/index.ts",
        output: [
            {
                file: packageJson.main,
                format: "cjs",
                sourcemap: false,
            },
            {
                file: packageJson.module,
                format: "esm",
                sourcemap: false,
            },
        ],
        plugins: [
            peerDepsExternal({
                includeDependencies: true,
                includeDevDependencies: true,
                includePeerDependencies: true,
            }),
            resolve({
                jsnext: true,
                main: true,
                browser: false,
                preferBuiltins: true,
            }),
            nodePolyfills(),
            json(),
            typescript({
                tsconfig: "./tsconfig.json",
            }),
            commonjs({
                namedExports: {
                    "react-js": ["isValidElementType"],
                },
            }),
            postcss(),
            babel({
                include: ["**.js", "node_modules/**"],
                babelHelpers: "bundled",
                presets: ["@babel/preset-env"],
            }),
            globals(),
            builtins(),
            uglify(),
        ],
        external: [
            "fs",
            "react",
            "react-is",
            "react-dom",
            "prop-types",
            "styled-components",
        ],
    },
    {
        input: "dist/esm/types/index.d.ts",
        output: [{ file: "dist/index.d.ts", format: "esm" }],
        external: [/\.css$/],
        plugins: [
            dts.default(),
            nodePolyfills(),
            copy({
                targets: [
                    { src: "src/components/app/fonts", dest: "dist/esm" },
                    { src: "src/components/app/fonts", dest: "dist/cjs" },
                ],
            }),
        ],
    },
];
```

Below is my config-overrides.js (webpack config) used with React-App-Rewired:

```
const MiniCssExtractPlugin = require("mini-css-extract-plugin");
module.exports = {
    plugins: [new MiniCssExtractPlugin()],
    module: {
        rules: [
            {
                test: /\.js?$/,
                loader: "babel-loader",
            },
            {
                test: /\.css$/i,
                use: [MiniCssExtractPlugin.loader, "css-loader"],
            },
        ],
    },
    resolve: {
        modules: ["app", "node_modules"],
        extensions: [".js", ".jsx", ".ts", ".tsx", ".css"],
        fallback: {
            fs: false,
            tls: false,
            net: false,
            path: false,
            zlib: false,
            http: false,
            https: false,
            stream: false,
            crypto: false,
        },
        mainFields: ["browser", "jsnext:main", "main"],
    },
    externals: {
        react: {
            root: "React",
            commonjs2: "react",
            commonjs: "react",
            amd: "react",
        },
        "react-dom": {
            root: "ReactDOM",
            commonjs2: "react-dom",
            commonjs: "react-dom",
            amd: "react-dom",
        },
    },
    node: {
        fs: "empty",
    },
    target: "web",
};
```

Below is my tsconfig.json:

```
{
    "compilerOptions": {
        "allowSyntheticDefaultImports": true,
        "esModuleInterop": true,
        "jsx": "react-jsx",
        "lib": ["es5", "es2015", "es2016", "dom", "esnext"],
        "types": ["node"],
        "module": "ESNext",
        "moduleResolution": "node",
        "noImplicitAny": false,
        "noUnusedLocals": false,
        "outDir": "dist",
        "sourceMap": true,
        "strict": true,
        "target": "es6",
        "strictNullChecks": true,
        "allowJs": true,
        "declaration": true,
        "declarationDir": "types",
        "typeRoots": ["dist/esm/types"]
    },
    "include": ["src/components/**/*"]
}
```

Everything works great when I use `npm start` and use the components from my local directory in src but the following scenarios both fail after creating the package using rollup:

1. Testing the package using `npm link test` and importing a component from the package, then then testing with `npm start`
2. Publishing the package to npm, installing from npm, then importing a component from the package, then testing with `npm start`

I receive the same error for both scenarios.

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

This is no longer an issue. The problem was with config-overrides.js. None of the configuration settings were being applied, specifically the fallback options. After changing the export from exporting an object literal to exporting a function and applying the options to the config options, the issues went away.

```
const MiniCssExtractPlugin = require("mini-css-extract-plugin");
module.exports = function override(config, env) {
    config.plugins = [new MiniCssExtractPlugin()];
    config.module = {
        rules: [
            {
                loader: "ts-loader",
                test: /\.(js|jsx|ts|tsx)$/,
                exclude: /node_modules/,
            },
            {
                test: /\.css$/i,
                use: [MiniCssExtractPlugin.loader, "css-loader"],
            },
            {
                test: /\.(woff|woff2|eot|ttf|otf)$/i,
                type: "asset/resource",
            },
        ],
    };
    config.resolve = {
        extensions: [".js", ".jsx", ".ts", ".tsx", ".css"],
        fallback: {
            assert: false,
            buffer: false,
            fs: false,
            tls: false,
            net: false,
            path: false,
            zlib: false,
            http: false,
            https: false,
            stream: false,
            crypto: false,
        },
    };
    config.externals = {
        react: {
            root: "React",
            commonjs2: "react",
            commonjs: "react",
            amd: "react",
        },
        "react-dom": {
            root: "ReactDOM",
            commonjs2: "react-dom",
            commonjs: "react-dom",
            amd: "react-dom",
        },
    };
    // config.node = {
    //  fs: "empty",
    // };
    config.target = "web";
    return config;
};
```